Entropy maximization of discrete PMF with expectation constraint, help me understand the solution
I've been given the following 3-part problem: 
Let $X$ be a discrete random variable (RV) over $\{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 10\}$, and let its PMF be $p(x) = \mathbb{P}[X = x]$. The Shannon entropy of $X$ is defined by
$$H(X) := \sum p(x) \log_2 \frac{1}{p(x)}.$$

Show that $H(X) \leq \log_2 11$ (Hint: use Jensen’s inequality).

What is the PMF that achieves the upper bound?

Using Lagrange multipliers, find
$$\max H(X) \quad \text{subject to} \quad \mathbb{E}[X] \leq 2.$$
My attempt 
I've proved the inequality and I managed to find the PMF that achieves the higher bound to be $p(x) = \frac{1}{11} \quad \forall x \in \{0,1,2,3,\dots, 10\}$ with lagrange multipliers, but I'm struggling with understanding and solving the last part of the problem. My prof has told us in relation to part 3 that "After solving Parts 1 and 2, you should conclude that the PMF maximizing entropy is achieved when the expectation is exactly 2." and so we can use lagrange multipliers.
My question is why? the Uniform distribution's expectation is 5, so I know we need something different to solve the problem but how do I know it'll achieve $\mathbb{E}[X]=2$?
and I'll be able to use Lagrange instead of KKT? also attempting to solve the last part with lagrange multipliers leaves me in a mathematical rabbit hole I'm not certain was intended: (how am I supposed to solve this analytically?)

$$\mathcal{L}(p(x), \lambda, \mu) = \sum_{x=0}^{10} p(x) \log_2 \frac{1}{p(x)} + \lambda \left( 1 - \sum_{x=0}^{10} p(x) \right) + \mu \left( 2 - \sum_{x=0}^{10} x \cdot p(x) \right)$$


$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial p(x)} = -\log_2 p(x) - \frac{1}{\ln(2)} + \lambda + \mu \cdot x = 0$$
$$p(x) = 2^{\lambda - \frac{1}{\ln(2)} + \mu \cdot x}$$
substituting it back into the constraints:
$$\sum_{x=0}^{10} 2^{\lambda - \frac{1}{\ln(2)} + \mu \cdot x }= 1$$ and
$$\sum_{x=0}^{10} x \cdot 2^{\lambda - \frac{1}{\ln(2)} + \mu \cdot x} = 2$$
how do I solve these two equations analytically?


you should conclude that the PMF maximizing entropy is achieved when the expectation is exactly 2
My question is why?

The entropy function $H$ is strictly concave, therefore it attains a unique maximum on the compact set $\Delta_{11}$ (=set of all probability distributions on ${0,1,\dots, 10}$). By part 2, you found that the argmax distribution $\mu_{max}$ has $E_{X\sim \mu_{max}}X=5$. If we now consider the smaller convex set $K=\{\mu\in\Delta_{11}: E_{\mu\sim X}X\leq 2\}$, then $H$ likewise attains a unique maximum over $K$, call it $\mu_K$. This maximum is either in the interior of $K$ or on the boundary of $K$.
If it is in the interior, then $mu_K$ is a local maximum. This is a contradiction, because a strictly concave function cannot have two local maxima. One way to see this directly is to consider $\lambda \mu_K+(1-\lambda)\mu_{max}$ for $0<\lambda<1$ and note by strict concavity that
$$H(\lambda \mu_K+(1-\lambda)\mu_{max})>\lambda H(\mu_K)+(1-\lambda)H(\mu_{max})=2\lambda +5(1-\lambda)>2$$
Thus as $\lambda\to 1$, we can construct distributions that are arbitrarily close to $\mu_K$ but have strictly larger entropy, which contradicts that $\mu_K$ is a local maximum.
This contradiction means that $\mu_K$ must lie on the boundary of $K$, as desired.

How to increase the $\mathbb{E}[X]$ to 2 without decreasing the entropy
Suppose that you have found a distribution $p(x)$ that has:

locally maximal entropy w.r.t. the $\sum_k p_k = 1$ constraint,
and $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_k kp_k < 2$.

You can choose any two different indices $i,j$ and "rebalance" the vector of probabilities by increasing $i$-th probability by $\eta$ and decreasing $j$-th probability: $p'_k = p_k, p'_i = p_i + \eta, p'_j = p_j - \eta$. In particular, if you do this for $i > j$, this change increases the expected value by $\eta(i-j)$.
To complete this reasoning, all we need to do is to find such a pair that also increases the entropy. Observe that the $k$-th derivative of $H$ is $-\left(\log_2 p_k + \frac{1}{\ln 2}\right)$, so if we make a step with small enough $\eta$, we will observe the entropy change close to $\eta \log_2 \frac{p_j}{p_i}$, which is nonnegative as long as $p_j > p_i$.
The only scenario when choosing such a pair of indices is impossible is when $$p_0 \le p_1 \le \cdots \le p_{10},$$ but the expected value of this distribution cannot be less than 5, the EV of the uniform distribution, contradicting the assumption that $\mathbb{E}[X] < 2$.
Solving the Lagrangean conditions
Disclaimer: this is not a full answer to your question; however, I think the insight I have here can still be useful.
The missing observation in your attempt to solve those equations is that your probabilities $p(x)$ form a geometric series: $$p(x) = 2^{\lambda-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}+\mu x}=2^{\lambda-\frac{1}{\ln(2)}} \times (2^\mu)^x = p_0 \times c^x$$ with $p_0 = p(0)$ and $c=2^\mu$. Given that, you can simplify the objective value at the stationary point: $$H=-\sum_{k=0}^{10} p(k) \log_2 p(k) = -\log_2 p_0 \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{10} p(k)}_{=1}  - \log_2 c \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{10} k p(k)}_{=2} = -\log_2 (p_0c^2) = -\log_2 p(2). $$
Now you have the following, arguably simpler but still not quite "closed-form" characterization of your answer: it is the negative logarithm of the third term $p_0c^2$ of a geometric series $p_0c^k, 0 \le k \le 10$, such that $$p_0(1+c+c^2 + \cdots + c^{10}) = 1$$ and $$p_0(0+c+2c^2 + \cdots + 10c^{10}) = 2.$$ In principle, both expressions on the left are polynomials, so you simplify them and find their zero $p_0, c_0$; however, I would expect that there is some smart way of exploring the geometric structure of the series to simplify those conditions even further.
